# Googlesheet importxml find value using xpath

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I need to get the integer value "maximum drawdown" from this website link =https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/1414510,

from google chrome i tried copy the xpath

```
//*[@id="radarChart"]/svg/text[8]/tspan[2]
```

then in google sheet, i write:

```
=importxml(https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/1414510, "//*[@id='radarChart']/svg/text[8]/tspan[2]")
```

It cant retrieve the value,
How to write the correct xpath to the value?
thanks

Comment: I understood that I could resolve your initial question. But I couldn't notice that you have the new 2nd question and unfortunately, I couldn't understand your 2nd question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new 2nd question. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### by xpath

Try for https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/1409351

```
=regexextract(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='s-data-columns hoverable']"),"\((.*)\)")
```

[image]

i highly recommand to test first this formula to have an overview

```
=importxml(A1,"//div[@class='s-data-columns hoverable']")
```

### by json

the second way could be to parse the json contained in the source (var radarChart)

```
function radarChart(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"")
  var data = source.split(`new svgRadarChart($('radarChart'),[`)[1].split(']')[0]
  var values = (data.match(/value : ([^,]+)/g))
  var names = (data.match(/name : ([^,]+)/g))
  var val
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){if (names[i]==`name : 'Maximum drawdown'`){val=values[i]}}
  return (val)
}
```

[image]

or

```
function radarChart(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"")
  var data = source.split(`new svgRadarChart($('radarChart'),[`)[1].split(']')[0]
  var values = (data.match(/value : ([^,]+)/g))
  var names = (data.match(/name : ([^,]+)/g))
  var result = []
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    result.push([names[i].replace('name : ','').replace(/'/g,''),values[i].replace('value : ','')])
  }
  return (result)
}
```

[image]